# Magento 2: How to Override the whole Admin Dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, dashboard

is there any way, that i can override the whole admin dashboard to customise and limit some features to display.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking at **[User Roles](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html)**. According to official document,

> To give someone restricted access to the Admin, the first step is to create a role that has the appropriate level of permissions. After the role is saved, you can add new users and assign the restricted role to grant them limited access to the Admin.

You can setup a role following the official document.

Comment: yes i did already what u said,  what i want is to override the dashboard , becoz i dont want to show customers details to admin user

Comment: You don't need coding either. Just remove the checkbox **Customers** on `System->User Roles->Your_Role->Role Resources`

Comment: yes i can do that, but i have to display the customers to admin user for some reason. so i want to display him only the specific customers by id which i will provide

Comment: i need the coding part for this to do override the dashboard

Comment: So, why not create one more role that's almost the same as admin, except cannot accessing Customer?

Comment: what do u mean by this

Comment: Create a role, without Customer access, others Allow